# TypeError: expected dynamic type 'string', but had type int64 in react-native Example for Android

Tags: react-native

I met this problem after load JS, any idea for this ? many thanks.

TypeError: expected dynamic type 'string', but had type 'int64'.

Comment: Please add tags!, and more explanations

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by react-native using the gradle package on the repository which is pre-built. If your version of react-native is from github then you are most likely to run into incompatible binaries.

Solution is to change the file in `ProjectName/android/app/build.gradle`

`compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.+'`

to

`compile project(':ReactAndroid')`

That way it will depend on your local library (and ofcourse you need to move the ReactAndroid folder to its correct position & you will need the android-ndk )

I would strongly recommend to wait for sometime.